# Azure Site Recovery - Keep Test Failover

Tags: azure, migration

I am using Azure Site Recovery to migrate a physical server to Azure. I have spun up a test failover VM and I want to keep it and stop the replication. Is this possible and how? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't retain a test. What your talking about is an actual fail over, so you would need to trigger that.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely possible. I performed the exact same thing about 12 months ago. From memory you can just remove the object from recovery services vault.

Let me get back to you on Monday when I'm back in the office to confirm what I did though.

Even without a specific process you can just copy your managed disk using powershell and create a new vm with the option to attach an existing disk.

Comment: Thanks. That is good to know as MS just told me it was not possible. In the end I did delete the test and complete a full failover, but good to know if I need it again.